# OnResume not called while dealing with surface view

Tags: android, surfaceview, onresume

My application has an mainActivity which sets view to a SurfaceView.

Application is started and displayed properly.
I press home button.-->onPause called,  Surfaceview is destroyed and Thread is killed properly.
Now when I click on my App again OnResume not called and I cannot see anything happen ,infact phone gets stuck.

I create a new thread every time I have a new surface.

I am not sure why there is problem with this code but I primarily suspect that something is mishandled in surfaceView.?

Please help!!

```
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    BounceLogger.logIt(this, "surfaceCreated");
    graphThread=new GraphUpdaterThread(mSurfaceHolder);
    graphThread.runThread();

}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    BounceLogger.logIt(this, "surfaceDestroyed");
    graphThread.stopThread();
    graphThread= null;
}






@Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        //handleProcessPaused();
        //mGsv.getThread().pauseThread();

        BounceLogger.logIt(this,"onPause()");        
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        //mGsv.getThread().resumeThread();
        //init();
        BounceLogger.logIt(this,"onResume()");      
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried calling surfaceChanged()? That method is called when the size is changed or first created.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the adb logcat of this? The error might be in the onCreate().

When onPause() is called, it then calls surfaceDestoryed() and then could call onDestroy().

When you reopen your application it could be calling onCreate() again and the error could happen at that time and thats why onResume() never gets called.

hard to debug without logcats.

Comment: my application doesn't call onResume but shows up the UI but if I press back button my application is stuck.

Comment: Technically the surface isn't destroyed until after onPause and before onStop. It's some fuzzy area.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of struggle I released what was wrong with my code.

Basically in the surfaceDestroyed I am calling stopThread which does the blocking  call currentThread.Join()
so my MainThread gets blocked and doesn't respond to anything.

```
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    BounceLogger.logIt(this, "surfaceDestroyed");
    graphThread.stopThread();                  
    graphThread= null;
}
```

My thread implementation

```
 public void run()
      {

          BounceLogger.logIt(this, "run start!!");
          while(!stop)
          {
              while(run)
              {
                updateThread(); 
              }
              if(!stop)
                  waitThread();
          }
          BounceLogger.logIt(this, "run end!!");
          return;
      } 

 public synchronized void stopThread()
  {
        run = false;     
        stop= true;
        boolean retry = true;
           while(retry)
           {
             try{
                Thread.currentThread.join();
                retry= false;
                }
             catch(Exception e)
             {
              } 
           }    
  }
```

I just removed join() in my stopThread function everything worked perfectly!!.

Note: I kill my threads by setting the flags stop,run and create a new thread every time!!